# DotNet Socket SetSocketOption No Operation

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I've been struggling to find a way to adding some TCP Option Headers. What I meant by Options are these part of bytes in the image link below from 20th Octets and so on.

[Tcp Options in Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFKRD.png)

So I've been creating a TcpClient basically, let's say :

```
TcpClient _client = new TcpClient();
```

I can basically access the Client property of this TcpClient object afterwards. From then there is a method SetSocketOption() which I was hoping to use in order to set the required TCP Options I needed. Below is the basic arguments required for this method. Basically it needs two Enum arguments which are predefined in System.Net.Sockets library and an OptionValue.

```
_client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName, int optionValue);
```

However the problem is there is no SocketOptionName which I require, that is the No-Operation Option and Timestamp Option. Referring to the website below, this Socket Option is indeed exist, so I'm curious why DotNet library doesn't implement this.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/tcp-parameters/tcp-parameters.xhtml

Anyhow, is there any other way to implement it, since the arguments require Enum variables that I cannot override or extend.

EDIT: I also understood by DotNet documentation below that the No-Operation and Timestamp option is not provided. Just wondering is there any chance to override those.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1011kecd(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be confusing options governing the operation of the socket itself (which `SetSocketOption()` allows you to change), with options that are part of the network transport layer, encoded in each TCP datagram header. I don't know why you think you want to set the values in the header, but you're probably going to have to use raw sockets to do that. Your question is very confusing...if you have an example of working code in some other context (e.g. C code for native Winsock or BSD sockets) to demonstrate what it is you're trying to do in .NET, that might help.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

To be more clear (hopefully) I understand that a normal TCPClient does not include the Options parameters on it's Header during transmission. I've seen it in a packet sniffer program also.

I edited the first post to show which are the Options

The problem is I am connecting to a device which requires these Options parameter to be existed on the TCP Header. The 'No Operation' or NOP itself basically just 4 bytes of zeroes used as a padding for the total packet.

I don't have a working code right now. But as you said maybe a raw socket is the best answer.

Comment: My point is that I believe raw socket is the _only_ answer. You're asking for `SetSocketOption()` to do something that has nothing to do with why that method exists in the first place. It's like asking `File.WriteAllText()` to draw a circle on the screen for you.

Comment: Ah, so that's what you've meant. So I'm mistaken regarding the functionality of the SetSocketOption itself. Since it has the same "Option" keyword, I though it was supposed to do something with the Option parameter on the TCP Header.

Anyway, I'm going to look into the raw socket, although I think it will not be easy to handle though... Thank you again for clarifying.